# Does uber central and Uber for business are same?

Tags: uber-api

> Is there any difference between Uber for business and Uber central?

Comment: This page might be helpful: https://www.uber.com/business/how-it-works?mainSite=true

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i actually wants to know is there any difference between them.